# How to crop image in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) to take photos. The taken photos are 16/9 ratio but I need them in 4/3.

Thus what I want is to crop the image to for example `1920*1440`.

I use [ImageEditor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imageeditor.html) from React Native. The code of `ImageEditor` can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageEditor.js).

My code is as follows :

```
this.camera.capture(target)
     .then((data) => {
           let cropData = {
               offset:{x:0,y:0},
               size:{width:1920, height:1440}
           };

           ImageEditor.cropImage(
                 data.path,
                 cropData, 
                 (uri) => {
                       this.props.captured(this.props.request, {
                             path: uri,
                             data: data.data,
                             longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                             latitude: position.coords.latitude
                             }
                       );
                       Actions.pop();
                 },
                 (error) => {});
            })
     .catch(err => {
           console.error(err)
     });
```

But the code above doesn't work. The saved photo isn't cropped and it is `1440*2560`.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what happens with your code in `captured()`, but I think the problem is that you're passing the original `data` to `this.props.captured`. My understanding from [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imageeditor#methods) is that:

> If the cropping process is successful, the resultant cropped image will be stored in the ImageStore, and the URI returned in the `success` callback will point to the image in the store.

So instead of reusing `data`, you should be reading the cropped image from `uri`